# Incorrect body height set using skrollr

Tags: skrollr

I am facing the same issue that the body height is too large. I tried using forceHeight: false but then I do not get any section to scroll. 
The page can be viewed here http://preview.sapientnitro.com.au/amf/desktop.html.

What could be wrong with my implementation as this page is responsive and so I should work with relative values. Would love to get the bottoms aligned.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I can see that many of your scrolling elements look odd, but not exactly sure what you are expecting.  Hint.  When I want things to line up perfectly, I create all my images as .png with largely transparent backgrounds. I ensure that ALL the images are the same height (and as appropriate width) and scale. Makes centering different elements and slide-ins way easy.  I do use vw and vh units a whole lot.  I've never touched `forceHeight`